# Русский язык и ncurses

Tags: c, linux, ncurses

В ncurses испытываю некоторые трудности при обработке русских символов. Вроде бы, все хорошо - printw("Русский текст") выводит "Русский текст". Однако при попытке создать меню, используя объект ITEM, пишу

```
my_items[0] = new_item("Русский текст", "");
printw(item_name(my_items[0]));
```

Ничего не выводится и, само собой, в меню пункт на русском языке тоже не отображается (и прекращается вывод каки-либо пунктов после этого). В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае вы используете `wchat_t*` строки, соответственно вам нужно линковаться с версией ncurses, поддерживающей wide characters. Попробуйте собрать программу с флагом `-lncursesw` вместо `-lncurses` и не забывайте выставлять соответствующую локаль:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "")
```

Comment: Ранее уже читал про это и повторял у себя - не помогло